# Extract pixel value and positions to a txt

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, image-processing

I have an image, for example

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPZM7.jpg"]
```

I would like to save in a text file the pixel positions and their values. At first I tried to export the table:

```
Table[{i, j, PixelValue[img, {i, j}][[1]], PixelValue[img, {i, j}][[2]],
       PixelValue[img, {i, j}][[3]]}, {i, 1, ImageDimensions[img][[1]]},
      {j, 1, ImageDimensions[img][[2]]}]
```

that what it is doing is a table with 5 columns: the first two columns are the pixel position (x,y) and the three last columns are the RED, GREEN, BLUE channel pixel values. When I do that, it takes like forever.

I would like to ask if there is a more efficient way to do such extraction and export the pixel information as the table I described above.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try this `Flatten[MapIndexed[Join[#2, #1] &, ImageData[img], {2}], 1]`

Comment: Ooohhhh thanks dear @swish, it works perfectly and very quick :-)

Comment: Try also `Flatten[
 Join[
  Outer[List, Sequence @@ N[Range /@ Reverse@ImageDimensions[img]], 1],
  ImageData[img],
  3
  ], 1]`